# Custom grpc version for Yocto-rocko cmake config problem

Tags: cmake, grpc, yocto

I am trying to add the grpc 1.46.7 to my rocko Yocto build. It looks fine until the config step which generates the following error:

`CMake Error: TRY_RUN() invoked in cross-compiling mode, please set the following cache variables appropriately: THREADS_PTHREAD_ARG (advanced)`

I have implemented the following patch https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/commit/d4e551a90b6bf6ea4e18fa408f40f39df6ad6fb4 to my cmake 3.8.2 that is used by rocko and I was hoping that was it.
However, this cmake is obviously not being used when configuring grpc because the error is still there.

My question is which cmake exactly is used when building with Yocto? I have checked my host PC and there is no cmake installed. I have tried `bitbake -c cleansstate grpc` but that didn't change anything.

Comment: Yocto builds and uses an internal version of cmake for reproducibility. You can check the version with `bitbake grpc -c devshell`, then run `cmake --version`. It should correspond to the cmake_*.bb files in your Yocto workspace.
Alternatively, run `bitbake -e cmake | grep PV`

Comment: I was patching the ```cmake``` in the wrong layer, that is why my changes weren't included. After I patched the ```cmake``` and ```cmake-native``` 3.8.2 in the poky layer it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Some Yocto layers already provide a gRPC recipe for rocko. Refer to https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/rocko/recipes/?q=grpc to find them.

You may add these layers to your `bblayers.conf` and use those recipes directly, or tweak them to your need.